# Reading xmlAttribute from XmlElement in jaxB

Tags: java, jaxb

Hello i have the following xml:

With the following code:

How can I get the attribute DispalyName of each element without creating new class for Down and Up and using @xmlAttribute.
I can solve it by adding new 2 classes UpElement and DownElement and for each class get the the @xmlAttribute but i want to it in once class.

```
Code Example:

        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


        @XmlRootElement(name = "StatusesList")
        @XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class StatusesListElement
        {

            @XmlElement(name = "Down")
            private String down = "";


            @XmlElement(name = "Up")
            private String up = "";


            public String getDown()
            {
                return down;
            }


            public void setDown(String down)
            {
                this.down = down;
            }


            public String getUp()
            {
                return up;
            }


            public void setUp(String up)
            {
                this.up = up;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

You could use the `@XmlPath` extension in **MOXy** to map this use case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "StatusesList")
@XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StatusesListElement
{

    @XmlPath("Down/@DisplayName")
    private String down = "";

    @XmlElement(name = "Up/@DisplayName")
    private String up = "";

}
```

**Using any JAXB Implementation**

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  Below is a link to an answer I gave that demonstrates how this can be done:

- [JAXB Element mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799081/jaxb-element-mapping/9802552#9802552)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer

Comment: Is there an option to set the  @XmlElement in  the runtime? and not hardcoded