# Jaxb tag embedded in tag

Tags: java, jaxb

I have XML like this:

```
   <FirstTag Attr="123">
     <WrapperTag>
       <EmbeddedTag>
       ....
       </EmbeddedTag>
     </WrapperTag>
   </FirstTag>
```

and code:

```
class FirstTag{
    EmbeddedTag tag;
}
```

i dont want write WrapperTag's class. What annotation should I use for EmbeddedTag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB Element mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799081/jaxb-element-mapping)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is it impossible to do via annotations?

Comment: I posted an answer to that question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802552/383861) that demonstrates how you can use the `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) to map that use case or an `XmlAdapter` with the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation with any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FirstTag")
```

above your first class, and then use:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Wrapper")
@XmlElement(name="Embedded Tag")
```

above your variables which you want as a wrapper and embedded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, that Embedded Tag element is not a Collection