# Marshalling/unmarshalling fields to tag with attributes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

Let's say I have class Example:

```
class Example{
  String myField;
}
```

I want to unmarshal it in this way:

```
<Example>
  <myField value="someValue" />
</Example>
```

Is it possible to unmarshal object in such way using JAXB XJC? ( I know about XmlPath in EclipseLink, but can't use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  In that `XmlAdapter` you will convert a `String` to/from an object that has one property mapped to an XML attribute.

**XmlAdapter**

```
package forum12914382;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MyFieldAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyFieldAdapter.AdaptedMyField, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedMyField v) throws Exception {
        return v.value;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMyField marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMyField amf = new AdaptedMyField();
        amf.value = v;
        return amf;
    }

    public static class AdaptedMyField {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String value;

    }

}
```

**Example**

```
package forum12914382;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="Example")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Example{

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyFieldAdapter.class)
    String myField;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12914382;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12914382/input.xml");
        Example example = (Example) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(example, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<Example>
  <myField value="someValue" />
</Example>
```

---

**Related Example**

- [JAXB Element mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799081/jaxb-element-mapping/9802552#9802552)

Comment: How can I access "value" attribute of "myField" in XmlAdapter?

Comment: @volodymyr -  The answer I linked to gives a full example of how this works.

Comment: doesn't work. maybe because in example you provided "theta" is not an attribute, but tag content and in my case value is an attribute of tag?

Comment: @volodymyr - The approach will definitely work.  Can you update your answer with what you have tried?

Comment: So in case if in example you provided I move "theta" from content of "beta" tag to it's attribute called "value" - nothing will change ?

Comment: I'm trying exactly what you proposed except I use "XmlAttribute" near my version of "theta"

Comment: @volodymyr - I have added a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, manually add the [@XmlAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html)-Annotation or generate the classes from an XSD.

Comment: XmlAttribute will map "myField"to <example myField="">, isn't it?